# How would you get number of days for each year in betwen dates in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

So I have a dataframe that has three columns a item coulmn and two date columns: sale_date and entry_date I want to create 4 extra columns 2017,2018,2019 and 2020. Each column has to contain the number of dates that each item spent before the sale a example would be dataframe1:

```
  item     Entry_date   Sale_date
dress      12/31/2017   10/31/2020
shoes       1/21/2018   9/10/2020
umbrella    6/14/2019   9/7/2020
car         12/31/2006  6/3/2020
```

Dataframe2:

```
item        Entry_date  Sale_date   2017    2018    2019    2020
dress       12/31/2017  10/31/2020  nan    365.00   365     305
shoes        1/21/2018  9/10/2020   nan    344.00   365     254
umbrella     6/14/2019  9/7/2020    nan     nan     200     251
car         12/31/2006  6/3/2020    4018   365.00   365     155
```

A code to the simple dataframe would be

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['dress','31/12/2017','31/10/2020'],['shoes','21/1/2018','10/9/2020'],['umbrella','14/6/2019','7/9/2020'],['car','31/12/2006','3/6/2020'],], columns=['item', 'entry_date', 'sale_date'])
```

All data below 2017 should be assumed as 2017 in the sense that no column below 2017 will be created. I am trying to do this with a 30,000 long item dataframe so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure how robust you needed this particular program to be. I did my best to handle the possible cases I could think of, but with the limited sample size it's hard to get a feel for the type of data you might be working with.

My approach was to generate a Series for every row which keys years to days passed in that year. (With the special condition of the lower bound)

```py
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, date

import pandas as pd


def get_days_as_series(start_date, end_date, lower_bound_year):
    if end_date < date(lower_bound_year, 1, 1):
        return None
    elif start_date.year == end_date.year:
        return pd.Series({start_date.year: (end_date - start_date).days})
    else:
        # If Lower Bound Year Defined
        last_day_lower_bound_year = date(lower_bound_year, 12, 31)
        if start_date < last_day_lower_bound_year:
            # Set Days in First Year to Years Before through last day of lower bound
            days_in_first_year = (last_day_lower_bound_year - start_date).days
        else:
            # Otherwise, calculate days to end of current year
            days_in_first_year = (date(start_date.year, 12, 31) - start_date).days
        # Calculate Days in last year
        first_year = max(lower_bound_year, start_date.year)
        n_days = {first_year: days_in_first_year}
        # Handle Years in Range
        # Start at max of lower bound year and current year
        for year in range(first_year + 1, end_date.year):
            # Handle Leap Years
            n_days[year] = 365 + (1 * calendar.isleap(year))

        if end_date.year >= lower_bound_year:
            # Days in Last Year
            n_days[end_date.year] = (end_date - date(end_date.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
        return pd.Series(n_days)


date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': {0: 'dress', 1: 'shoes', 2: 'umbrella',
                            3: 'car', 4: 'ends before start'},
                   'entry_date': {0: '31/12/2017', 1: '21/1/2018', 2: '14/6/2019',
                                  3: '31/12/2006', 4: '15/4/2007'},
                   'sale_date': {0: '31/10/2020', 1: '10/9/2020', 2: '7/9/2020',
                                 3: '3/6/2020', 4: '28/5/2010'}})

df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'], format=date_format)
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], format=date_format)

df = df.merge(
    df.apply(
        lambda s: get_days_as_series(s['entry_date'].date(),
                                     s['sale_date'].date(),
                                     lower_bound_year=2017),
        axis=1
    ), left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                item  entry_date   sale_date    2017   2018   2019   2020
0              dress  31/12/2017  31/10/2020     0.0  365.0  365.0  305.0
1              shoes   21/1/2018   10/9/2020     NaN  344.0  365.0  254.0
2           umbrella   14/6/2019    7/9/2020     NaN    NaN  200.0  251.0
3                car  31/12/2006    3/6/2020  4018.0  365.0  365.0  155.0
4  ends before start   15/4/2007   28/5/2010     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

---

Some Notes and Assumptions:

Notes:

1. Currently only the Lower Bound is implemented meaning that if you have 2021 dates you'll end up with a 2021 column. You can edit to include a min on an upper bound.
2. You did not specify how to handle the case where the end date occurs before  2017. I added this example with index 4, currently I just return None which results in NaNs across. If you wanted to have the days that occurred before 2017 in the 2017 column you can just omit the lines:

```py
if end_date < date(lower_bound_year, 1, 1):
    return None
```

Assumptions:

1. The `sale_date` always comes after the `entry_date`. If this is incorrect you will have to update the conditions in `get_days_as_series` to handle it appropriately.

---

For completeness sake, I'm including a version which will return all values for every year without the lower bound, in case someone finds this question later and is looking for that kind of functionality:

```py
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, date

import pandas as pd


def get_days_as_series(start_date, end_date):
    if start_date.year == end_date.year:
        return pd.Series({start_date.year: (end_date - start_date).days})
    else:
        days_in_first_year = (date(start_date.year, 12, 31) - start_date).days
        n_days = {start_date.year: days_in_first_year}
        for year in range(start_date.year + 1, end_date.year):
            n_days[year] = 365 + (1 * calendar.isleap(year))

        n_days[end_date.year] = (end_date - date(end_date.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
        return pd.Series(n_days)


date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': {0: 'dress', 1: 'shoes', 2: 'umbrella',
                            3: 'car', 4: 'ends before start'},
                   'entry_date': {0: '31/12/2017', 1: '21/1/2018', 2: '14/6/2019',
                                  3: '31/12/2006', 4: '15/4/2007'},
                   'sale_date': {0: '31/10/2020', 1: '10/9/2020', 2: '7/9/2020',
                                 3: '3/6/2020', 4: '28/5/2010'}})

df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'], format=date_format)
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], format=date_format)

df = df.merge(
    df.apply(
        lambda s: get_days_as_series(s['entry_date'].date(),
                                     s['sale_date'].date()),
        axis=1
    ), left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                item  entry_date   sale_date  2006   2007   2008   2009   2010   2011   2012   2013   2014   2015   2016   2017   2018   2019   2020
0              dress  31/12/2017  31/10/2020   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    0.0  365.0  365.0  305.0
1              shoes   21/1/2018   10/9/2020   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  344.0  365.0  254.0
2           umbrella   14/6/2019    7/9/2020   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  200.0  251.0
3                car  31/12/2006    3/6/2020   0.0  365.0  366.0  365.0  365.0  365.0  366.0  365.0  365.0  365.0  366.0  365.0  365.0  365.0  155.0
4  ends before start   15/4/2007   28/5/2010   NaN  260.0  366.0  365.0  148.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```